# performSelectorOnMainThread to update UI doesn't work

Tags: ios, user-interface

I am trying to update the UI with `performSelectorOnMainThread`. When I use `performSelectorOnMainThread`, it only works at first. However, when I switch views and come back to the initial view, it no longer works (the function is still being called properly).

For debugging purposes, I put a button that calls the same function to update the UI. The button press works every time (even after switching views). Any ideas?

Comment: Just to be clear: You have a function which updates the UI, which works when it gets called in response to pushing a button, but when it gets called using performselectoronmainthread, and you know it is successfully being called, it stops working at some point.  Could you provide more detail as to what about it isn't working, and/or how do you know the function is getting executed?

Comment: Are you using GCD?  Or is this a performSelectorInBackground?  (I only ask because a nested dispatch might be the answer).